# Table footer with sum for numbers and average for percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table that looks like this:

```
      |       H1        |
  H1  |-----------------|
      |  H2  |    H2    |
------------------------|
Text  |Number|Percentage|
------------------------|
Text  |Number|Percentage|
------------------------|
...
```

Is there a way to add "Total" footer that will look like this:

```
      |       H1        |
  H1  |-----------------|
      |  H2  |    H2    |
------------------------|
Text  |Number|Percentage|
------------------------|
Text  |Number|Percentage|
------------------------|
...
------------------------|
Total:|Sum   |Avg prcntg|
------------------------|
```

using JS, that will take into account class of a cell (percentage, number) and calculate total for columns accordingly?

There is a few somewhat similar solutions, but I'm new to JS (and HTML for that matter) and can't modify them myself. I would aslo greatly appreciate if you throw in some comments along the solution, so I could actually learn something :)

```
<table border="1"> 
<thead>
  <th rowspan="2">Header</th>
  <th colspan="2">Header</th>
  <tr>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    <th>Percentages</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td class="number">1</td>
  <td class="percentage">30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td class="number">2</td>
  <td class="percentage">40</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>  
<tfoot>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td class="result"></td>
  <td class="result"></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

#### EDIT

Okay, I fiddled around with other solutions a bit more and here what I made:

```
var totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var tbodyrows = $('#myTable tbody').find('tr').length;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dataRows = $("#myTable tbody tr");
  $dataRows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('.number').each(function(i) {
      totals[i] += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
  });
  $("#myTable tfoot td:not(:first-child)").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("result")) {
      $(this).text(totals[i]);
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("perresult")) {
      $(this).text(totals[i] / tbodyrows);
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aky2qaq8/)

That works, but what if I want it to **make** footer, instead of populating premade one?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible. Where did you get stuck with your own attempts? What specific help did you need?

Comment: I more or less tried to just copypaste some similar solutions, so there is not much to show. Here is my best "attempt" so far -  https://jsfiddle.net/Lj3ftq2n/ . It works for this exact table, but I don't know how to "reset" it for tables with more "number" or "percentage" columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the totals to the table yourself, you are likely looking for something like jQuery's .append function. This will let you add on new table rows to the end of the table, once you've calculated the totals. Link to docs: http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
    // JavaScript: (comments below each line start with //)
    var tableHtml = ''; 
    // new empty string variable to put your table html in
    tableHtml += ''; 
    // this starts a new table row (tr), += adds more to the existing value
    tableHtml += 'Text'; 
    // this is the text column (cell)
    tableHtml += ''+numberTotal+''; 
    // the js number variable in a new cell
    tableHtml += ''+percentTotal+''; 
    // the js percent variable in a new cell
    tableHtml += ''; 
    // the end of a new table row
    $( "table" ).append(tableHtml); 
    // appends this html as a child of "table" or "tbody" if that works better
```

You may need to use some of the other comments above to get the totals, but my answer shows how to add it to the table after the page is loaded in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done.You can get the elements using jquery and run a loop to find the total and average percentage as follows:

```
var numbers=$('.number')
var percentage=$('.percentage')
var avg=0;
var total=0;
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
   total=total+parseInt(numbers.eq(i).text())
   avg=avg+parseInt(percentage.eq(i).text())
}
$('.result').eq(0).text(total)
$('.result').eq(1).text(percentage/numbers.length)
```